# How targeting .NET 4.0 with Mvvmcross?

Tags: mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I want to use Mvvmcross to make application for several platforms.

I use Profile 104 for PCL library like Mvvmcross, but this profile target .NET 4.5.
I want to target .NET 4.0 to use my application on Windows XP.

To do that, I add the xml files

> MonoAndroid, Version = v1.6 +. Xml

and

> VSMonoTouch, Version = v1.0 +. Xml

in the profile 143 which allows me to target. NET framework 4.0.3.

However, I have a compilation error because it can not find the ICommand interface.
This interface is not in the same library between version 4.0 and 4.5, is it why it doesn't work ?
Or should I recompile all Mvvmcross libraries with profile 143?

thanks,

Answer (score 5):

This is a Portable Class Library limitation.

See the table on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx

> Model-View-View Model (MVVM)
>
> Only 4.5

This means that if anyone wants to use MvvmCross on earlier .Net platforms then someone has to build and maintain a non-PCL version.

Since the maintainer of Mvx (me!) has decided to only maintain PCL versions of MvvmCross, then any non-PCL support will have to be created by the community.

For WPF this shouldn't be too large or difficult a job - but it might be...

---

Alternatively, somebody *might* be able to do *something funky* to get the `ICommand` working... I've retagged this question with `portable-class-library` to try to lure in some of the MS experts.

Comment: To be fair to MS, targeting XP is targeting an operating system from 2001

Comment: Also, the Mono mkbundle tool can be used to bundle the Mono library with a Windows application. I assume the Mono 3 mkbundle tool will enable .NET 4.5 on Windows XP, with the added bonus of not requiring a .NET install at all, and getting the same runtime characteristics of any other platforms the application is being used with.